# node-gyp rebuild error on docker hyperledger indy

Tags: dockerfile, node-gyp, hyperledger-indy

I am using hyperledger indy for my thesis. Indy runs on docker. But whenever I try to build my docker-compose, `npm install` command in agentDockerfile throws node-gyp rebuild error.I am installing node v10.Can anyone please help?
My agentDockerfile

```
FROM bcgovimages/von-image:py36-1.6-8

USER root

# Install nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y \
        nodejs \
        build-essential

USER indy

WORKDIR $HOME

RUN mkdir nodejs
WORKDIR nodejs

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.local/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib

# Get the dependencies loaded first - this makes rebuilds faster
COPY --chown=indy:indy package.json .
RUN npm install

# Copy rest of the app
COPY --chown=indy:indy . .
RUN chmod uga+x scripts/* bin/*

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

EXPOSE 8000
```

error:

```
> indy-sdk@1.6.1 install /home/indy/nodejs/node_modules/indy-sdk
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.22.46:443
gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.0-kali3-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/indy/nodejs/node_modules/indy-sdk
gyp ERR! node -v v8.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN The package just-extend is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! indy-sdk@1.6.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the indy-sdk@1.6.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/indy/.npm/_logs/2021-07-04T09_53_53_155Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'alice' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "indy-agent",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha test/**/*.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.5.7",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "home-dir": "^1.0.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "indy-sdk": "1.6.1",
    "json-stringify-pretty-compact": "^1.2.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.5",
    "session-file-store": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^5.1.1",
    "sinon": "^5.0.7",
    "just-extend": ">=4.0.0"
  }
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04